# What is the fastest way to format a large number of date/time objects in Android?

Tags: android, performance

I am looking for the quickest method of generating a long list of date/times that will be used  in a text file output. An example of what I am trying to achieve:

1, 2013-10-17 00:00:00,data,data
2, 2013-10-17 00:00:01,data,data
3, 2013-10-17 00:00:02,data,data
....

This is a format I must conform with and cannot be changed. This data can easily reach 100,000+ lines. What I am currently doing is :

```
//text_output is a printstream to SD card
logged_time = Calendar.getInstance();
dateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// these values are gathered from a device via bluetooth
logged_time.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

while(I_still_have_lines_to_process){
    // print the line
    text_output.print(line_count + "," + dateFormat.format(logged_time.getTime()) + data etc.)
    // add the sample rate to calculate next date/time
    logged_time.add(Calendar.SECOND, sample_rate);
}
```

I have found that for 250k lines this process takes ~50 seconds for the formatting alone. I also must parse the data itself and transfer via Bluetooth. The user experience would be greatly improved if I could speed this up. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Thanks for the response. The Bluetooth communications are actually quite a bit faster since I am only transferring a couple bytes per line. I have also looked into solutions where this data is sat in an asynctask on its own while the data comes in, then putting it all back together in the end. However, I have found that I run out of memory quickly this way as I end up with a few copies of the data

Comment: Just to be sure - are you absolutely sure that the formatting is the problem and not I/O? Have you profiled it and seen that most of the time is spent in `format()`?

Comment: have you tried using a StringBuilder to append all data and print/stream the data only once?

Comment: Hi mikel. Yes, I actually started this way to make sure the data was set up properly. The printstream, even at over 100k lines, prints nearly instantly . I didn't see any decrease in performance between appending or just sending right to the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote your code to something I could actually run and test and ended up with the below code. It's crude, but works for me and I'll base my work on it. Please go through it if there's something that doesn't match your actual behaviour.

```
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Calendar logged_time = Calendar.getInstance();
    Format dateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("out.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            // print the line
            writer.write(i + ", " + dateFormat.format(logged_time.getTime()));
            writer.newLine();

            // add the sample rate to calculate next date/time
            logged_time.add(Calendar.SECOND, SAMPLE_RATE);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + " ms");
}
```

When I run this on my machine, I get exactly 1000 ms on average.

Simply changing

```
dateFormat.format(logged_time.getTime())
```

to

```
dateFormat.format(logged_time)
```

resulted in 730 ms on average. You don't need to make new `Date` objects every time.

But we can do better! There is a *lot* of repeated work - we don't have to format the whole date every time again and again. Let's cache most of the formatted date and only check whether we have to reformat it when seconds overflow:

```
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Calendar logged_time = Calendar.getInstance();
    Format dateFormatNoSecs = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:");
    Format dateFormatSecs = FastDateFormat.getInstance("ss");

    String lastFormattedDateNoSecs = dateFormatNoSecs.format(logged_time);
    int lastSecs = logged_time.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("out.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            int secs = logged_time.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            if (secs < lastSecs) {
                // at least minutes changed, we need to reformat it
                lastFormattedDateNoSecs = dateFormatNoSecs.format(logged_time);
            }
            // print the line
            writer.write(i + ", " + lastFormattedDateNoSecs + dateFormatSecs.format(logged_time));
            writer.newLine();

            // add the sample rate to calculate next date/time
            logged_time.add(Calendar.SECOND, SAMPLE_RATE);
            lastSecs = secs;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + " ms");
}
```

610 ms.

Last microoptimizations: A custom manual formatter for seconds. Strangely enough, `DecimalFormat` is was slower than `FastDateFormat` for seconds formatting. But a simple switch is the fastest:

```
public class TwoDigitIntegerFormatter {

    public static String format(int number) {
        assert (number >= 0) && (number <= 99);

        switch (number) {
            case 0: return "00";
            case 1: return "01";
            case 2: return "02";
            case 3: return "03";
            case 4: return "04";
            case 5: return "05";
            case 6: return "06";
            case 7: return "07";
            case 8: return "08";
            case 9: return "09";
            default: return String.valueOf(number);
        }
    }

}
```

And we can maintain the second count manually, too:

```
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Calendar logged_time = Calendar.getInstance();
    Format dateFormatNoSecs = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:");

    String lastFormattedDateNoSecs = dateFormatNoSecs.format(logged_time);
    int secs = logged_time.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("out.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            if (secs > 59) {
                // at least minutes changed, we need to reformat it
                lastFormattedDateNoSecs = dateFormatNoSecs.format(logged_time);
                secs %= 60;
            }
            writer.write(i + ", " + lastFormattedDateNoSecs + TwoDigitIntegerFormatter.format(secs));
            writer.newLine();

            // add the sample rate to calculate next date/time
            logged_time.add(Calendar.SECOND, SAMPLE_RATE);
            secs += SAMPLE_RATE;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
}
```

510 ms. Even if your code is not exactly the same, you can use the ideas from this solution to help yourself.

Comment: Hi Slanec,

Thank you so much for this detailed response! I used some of these tips alongside a few other changes and was able to reduce the time spent looping by ~75%. First, I got rid of using date formatting at all by setting variables for H/M/S/D/M/YY (using calendar.get(calendar.second) etc.) I then manually create the strings by appending these variables with the proper dashes and semicolons into a stringbuilder before storing them in a string arraylist. I then set the length of the stringbuilder to 0 and move to the next line.

Comment: Finally, I put all of this code back into its own asynctask as the necessary information is known as soon as the device connects. Now instead of taking ~54s for 250k lines I am down to ~14s!